# Disable the hash change controller in JQuery mobile UI and replace with backbone.js

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, mobile, backbone.js, hashchange

I'm using **JQuery Mobile UI** and the widgit kit is nice. However I'm also using backbone.js which comes with a really neat hashchange controller framework. Problem is that JQuery Mobile UI has an inbuilt crappy hash change controller which assumes you willl **always** want to make an AJAX query on every hash change and load the content from the server.

Has anybody had any success in just pulling out the widget framework from JQuery Mobile UI?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like this has been solved in a current commit to jquery mobile UI.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/commit/3162428558efd9960739ef8f00a7ead0dbf6d3ec

Comment: Note that you have to set linkBindingEnabled to false in version 1.0