# Mobile gestures in backbone.js

Tags: events, jquery-mobile, backbone.js

Can I have mobile gestures like swipe, tap, pinch etc in the Backbone.js View events? To be more specific following is my code.

```
Backbone.View.extend({
     initialize:function(){
        //initialization 
     },
     Events:{
          "swipe-left #homeBtn":"homeSwipe"
     },
     homeSwipe:function(){
        alert("Event Swipe left triggered!");
     }
});
```

Can I have the mobile gestures like swipe, swipe-left/right, pinch, tap etc to work with backbone.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backbone [relies on jQuery.bind](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1236) to manage the DOM events.

So the question is that if jQuery supports these events and looks like [jQuery Mobile does](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/mobile-events-documentation), now you have to check [how to integrate jQuery Mobile and Backbone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537993/how-to-use-jquery-mobile-and-backbone-js-together-in-one-app).

Comment: Que hondas @gguillen, I honestly don't think it does. The swipe effects seem like it can target the `el` directly, but none of its children divs

Answer (score 8):

Download and include [Hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js/) and then use Backbone view events like normal!

```
events:{
    'swipe': 'onSwipe'
},

initialize: function(){
    // I think you can get away doing this here once, but I have not tested.
    // If not, just move it to the `render` method
    new Hammer(this.el);
},

onSwipe: function(e){
    console.log(e.direction); // left or right
}
```

Also, you could take a look at my simple [Backbone view Gist](https://gist.github.com/4279025)

#### Update

Based on the feedback, it looks like `new Hammer(this.el)` must be called on the backbone view for this to work. I've updated the example to reflect this.

Comment: This works like a charm. The only thing needs to be added - that 'adapter' between hammer.js and jquery should be added to make this code work. It can be found here: https://raw.github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/master/jquery.specialevent.hammer.js

Comment: For this to work, I had to call the `hammer()` function on my view's `$el` like this `this.$el.hammer()` from within the `render()` method of my View. 

I got this from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16092066/877353), although I do need [the jquery plugin](http://hammerjs.github.io/jquery-plugin/) for this to work

Comment: @AlexandreBourlier – I updated my answer to show your said requirement. I think I've provided an example without the need for the jquery plugin though.