# using backbone.js with hammer.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, hammer.js

Would like to know if anyone have used backbone with hammer.js and how to implement the `Backbone.View` with the drag, hold events of hammer.js?

Comment: Found this link in another post

http://www.undiscoveredfeatures.com/2012/04/using-raphaeljs-and-backbonejs-together.html

which specify how to use raphael.js with backbone, however it would be good if someone can give more advice on it?  It looked a little alien...

Comment: Here is the answer for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13922369/1102013

Answer (score 2):

You can't use Hammerjs events in delegateEvents directly, but there are plugins that patch Backbone.View to make it possible: https://github.com/wookiehangover/backbone.hammer.js